# What happened to the mini boss that flew in by eagle?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm playing dark souls 2 and I've gotten to the part where I'm stuck in between the first mini boss of Cathedral of Blue and going to no man's wharf. What I've found out that I can skip no mans wharf together (my walk through is telling me about all this crap that I have to go through and there isn't even items that'd I want) but it also tells me of this other boss in forest of fallen giants, but I already skipped him by falling off the pedestal and now he will not respawn, please is no mans warf easy to get through or is it better to find a way to get the eagle boss to reappear and beat him. Or can I just altogether skip the boss and find the so called eagle nest? And if it's worth anything I'm a melee character and I've already defeated the Last Giant.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are referring to  [the pursuer](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dark-souls-2/The_Pursuer). He will appear to you in the forest of fallen giants first, (dropped off by an eagle) if you die, or skip it, he will appear at the top of the castle and this is one of the paths to No man's wharf (via the eagle). You CAN skip him and go to no man's wharf from beating [the old dragonrider](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/dark-souls-2-walkthrough-guide-part-2/1100-6418242/). You CAN skip No man's wharf but there are some good items and NPCs (a magic dealer and an NPC that BUYS your items for souls) so you might want to go through it. As far as ease, I wouldnt say no man's wharf is the hardest place, but you will die quite a bit (just like most areas). I think I saw that the pursuer also appears later in the Iron keep if you dont defeat him on top of the castle.

Comment: Thanks, this just what I needed to know, I just don't like dying so many times like I do, I the best gamer there ever was ya know

Comment: just like to add: The Pursuer will confront you in the Smelter Demon's arena (if you come back after killing the demon) whether you've killed him in the Forest of Fallen Giants or not.

Answer (score 3):

Pursuer is the boss you're talking about.  He is the second area boss of the Forest of Fallen Giants.  He is an optional boss, since you can get to Lost Bastille without having to deal with him by going through No Man's Wharf.

You have already beaten the Last Giant, so you have the solider's key.  There's a door that's very close to the lift and shortcut for the first boss that this key opens.  Go through and up some stairs and you'll be fighting Pursuer.  If you're not interested in No Man's Wharf (which I think is a little easier and has an easier boss then Pursuer), then you'll want to defeat Pursuer here.

It shouldn't matter if you fought him in the middle area or not.  You'll still have to take him on as a boss here.

Remember, however, that the beginning part of Lost Bastille is actually locked out for you if you don't go through No Man's Wharf.  It's locked until you can beat the area boss for Lost Bastille.  There's a gate you can't open from the Tower side that bars you from the beginning area.  There's not much there, but it's still something to notice.

Comment: Thank you it's a bit more descriptive then last one, this will be very helpful ;)

Comment: `It shouldn't matter if you fought him in the middle area or not. You'll still have to take him on as a boss here.` Not true. You can fight him early OR as a boss on the roof. You can't defeat him twice in the Forest of the Fallen Giants without an Ascetic.

Answer (score 0):

After you beat the Last Giant, use the Soldier key to open a door in the castle corridor with one wall open to the sea; you pass through that corridor right before you get to the room with the shortcut door to the elevator that takes you down to the Last Giant.

The door has a small stairway on the right and a platform with a chest above it. After you pass through the door you'll go up a few flights of stairs, where you'll find the fog gate to the arena where the actual Pursuer boss fight takes place.